# Safari Web Inspector: What is the difference between request and response local overrides?

Tags: safari, devtools, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to read the docs on Safari Inspector's Local Overrides [here](https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/). It talks about Request and Response overrides, but I am not understanding the difference between the two.

[image]

I am trying to make edit a request to make it send a different value than what's currently being send. Is it possible with request overrides?